# I have thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, object, nullpointerexception

In this code I have `NullPointerException` error:

```
int k=3;
Thread[] th = null ;
for(int i=0; i<k; i++){
    th[i] = new ThreadF(step[i],step[i+1],"Th"+(i+1));                       
}
```

But in this no error and everything is fine:

```
Thread th1 = new ThreadF(step[0],step[0+1],"Th1");
Thread th2 = new ThreadF(step[1],step[1+1],"Th2");
Thread th3 = new ThreadF(step[2],step[2+1],"Th3");
```

Why?

Comment: `th = null`, that's why.

Answer (score 4):

```
Thread[] th = null;
```

Should be:

```
Thread[] th = new Thread[k];
```

If you enable warnings, or use an IDE, you should see:

> Null pointer access: The variable th can only be null at this location